# Change Frame Title

Tags: frames, frame-title-format

I'm reading [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FrameTitle) that I can change frame title, like this

```
(setq frame-title-format "Church of Emacs")
```

, but nothing seems to happen, when listing the window titles:

```
$wmctrl -l
0x05e000aa  0 spartacus home.dot.emacs.dot.d.emacsen.org - GNU Emacs at spartacus
0x08600002  0 spartacus alacritty-j
0x01200120  0 spartacus Mozilla Firefox
```

Is this supposed to work dynamically when I evaluate that?

Comment: It worked for me.  The window title changed immediately after evaluation.

Comment: Me too - except that I had to do a refresh: `C-l` worked to refresh as did creating a second frame, or trying  to execute an extended command with `M-x `: the title changed at that point. I suspect a lot of different actions would accomplish the refresh . `wmctrl -l` showed the old title before the refresh, the new title afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me. Have you tried starting Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If that works for you then bisect your init file to find the culprit.

By "works" I mean that *the frame title changes in Emacs*.

Perhaps your question is instead a non-Emacs question, about some command-line command `wmctrl`? If you see the frame title change in Emacs, but that's not reported by some outside command, then maybe post your question on a different site, such as StackOverflow, as a question about that command?